# Generating histograms to analyse different sets of image data in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to analyse two sets of image data. Each set consists of 10000 images. The main idea is to check how different are these two sets.

One way to statistically analyse is through histograms.
I checked the `cv2.hist()` function in Python, but it only generates histograms for one image. Can anyone help me generate histograms for the complete image set?

Comment: Just use the manual numpy-based hist-calculation shown [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html). Do this for each image and sum up the different hists. But be careful with automatic bin-inference. Better to chose the number a-priori which probably assumes the same range . Even better: give the bins explicitly. Then you an plot this with matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you. It works